# Inserting image in a message box

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, messagebox

I was wondering how I would make an image appear inside a messagebox that I set up so that whenever the mouse enters a label, it displays the messagebox. What would the code be for the image insertion?

Comment: You can't. You will have to write your own `MessageBox`.

Comment: That is what I mean, how do I write a MessageBox that will display an image?

Comment: You have this tagged as asp.net, are you talking about a popup on a web page?

Comment: Kind of? haha, I built a little maze in a windows application form and I want to make it a screaming maze.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick and dirty way to achieve this is to create another windows form that will have same buttons as message box but that will also have an image.

[image]

- Create public Boolean property in this form that will be named something like OKButtonClicked that will tell you whether OK or Cancel was clicked
- Set ControlBox property to False so that minimize, maximize and close buttons are not shown

Here is a code behind for this form

```
public partial class MazeForm : Form
{
    public MazeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool okButton = false;

    public bool OKButtonClicked
    {
        get { return okButton; }
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        okButton = true;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        okButton = false;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Finally in your main form you can do something like this

```
MazeForm m = new MazeForm();
m.ShowDialog();

bool okButtonClicked = m.OKButtonClicked;
```

Note that this is something I quickly created in 15 min and that it probably needs more work but it will get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you hahaha, I didn't even think about using another windows form.